# Clang + iOS + assembler jump: error "unsupported relocation on symbol"

Tags: ios, assembly, arm, clang, arm64

I have assembler code for ARM32, on Android it compiles well, but for iOS it throws the error "unsupported relocation on symbol" on the jump instruction. For Android64 and iOS64 the same situation.

```
clang -target armv7m-none-ios-gnueabi "test.c"
```

```cpp
void func()
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        "eor r0, 0 \n\t" 
        "cmp r0, 0 \n\t"
        "beq .done \n\t" /*!!!*/
        "eor r0, 0 \n\t"
    ".done: \n\t"
        "bx lr \n\t"
    );
}
```

At the same time, no problems arise in Godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/lr2bsZ.
I use the Clang compiler 8.0.0.

Comment: Why do you need asm for this? Also, `eor` with zero seems pointless. Anyway, try using a local label instead.

Comment: I have a lot of complex assembler code. This example is just a minimal example of how to reproduce the error. Instead of eor, there can be any instruction.

Comment: I doubt the `eor` makes a difference. A [mcve] would likely just be a `beq .done; .done:` In general I would avoid symbols with leading dots as directives usually take that form, unless I know it's safe for your assembler.

Comment: You're right. In any case, it does not matter. It's okay to name labels starting with a dot. But if you change the dot to any character - the situation will not change.

Comment: I assume that's a linker error? So maybe compile to object only and dump the relocations to see what it generated. Also, put some condition in C to have the compiler also emit some branching and compare to what you got. You could also use a separate assembly file and see if that works (would be a recommended solution anyway if you don't absolutely require inlining).

Comment: No, this is a compilation error. When test.c compiles to test.o.

Comment: That's strange, compilation doesn't normally deal with relocations. Also the command you showed is not producing an object (or clang works differently than gcc)

Comment: @Jester: The assembler has to encode relocations into the object files.  If for some reason it thought a branch target was unreachably far away it might output that message.  You can get messages like that for `ldr reg, =symbol ^ 0x1234` because there's no relocation for address XOR constant, for example.  But I don't see anything that would be a problem here unless this inlines multiple times and the duplicate labels end up giving the "wrong" error message.  So maybe use `%=` or whatever it is to add a unique ID number to the asm label, as well as calling it `.L` something local.

Comment: did you try -save-temps, I see a problem with the asm generated when done that way.

Comment: how are you cross compiling to a binary with clang?  or lets say linking.  creating the object is fine. which implies the label is fine.

Comment: which is what you are doing in godbolt, an apples to oranges comparison to your clang command line shown.

Comment: @PeterCordes, this code does not compile: void func()
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        "beq .Ldone \n\t" /*!!!*/
    ".Ldone: \n\t"
        "bx lr \n\t"
 );
}

Comment: @old_timer, this flag causes an error "unknown directive".

Comment: exactly.........

Answer (score 4):

The label needs to be local, i.e. start with an uppercase `L`. Note that this is different from ELF targets, where local labels start with `.L`.

This code compiles fine for me:

```
void func()
{
    __asm__ volatile
    (
        "eor r0, 0 \n\t" 
        "cmp r0, 0 \n\t"
        "beq Ldone \n\t" /*!!!*/
        "eor r0, 0 \n\t"
    "Ldone: \n\t"
        "bx lr \n\t"
    );
}
```

As a side note though, you might want to write your function entirely in assembly as follows, because as far as I'm aware there is no guarantee that the compiler won't insert code before or after your assembly that breaks your assumptions. So I'd suggest something like this:

```
__asm__
(
"_func: \n"
    "eor r0, 0 \n" 
    "cmp r0, 0 \n"
    "beq Ldone \n"
    "eor r0, 0 \n"
"Ldone: \n"
    "bx lr \n"
);
```

Comment: @Listener: Probably worth mentioning that the first example here is broken because it uses `bx lr` from inside the inline asm without using `asm goto` or `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm.  If it modified `r0`, it would also be broken for leaving out `r0` from the clobber list (Extended asm).  And it's already broken for clobbering condition-codes with `cmp` (a `"cc"` clobber).  Using `asm` at global scope to declare a pure-asm function label/symbol is valid, though, if you want to avoid using a separate `.S` file, but then you're not getting any benefit (inlining) of inline asm.